# Issue in getting value from $_GET PHP

Tags: php, html

I am getting a value from URL using $_GET and the variable is message with data like

```
 message=<b>Volatino+riepilogo+ordine%3A<%2Fb>+<br%2F>+<br%2F>Layout+selezionato%3A+<b>2<%2Fb><br%2F>Slogan+%3A+asd<br%2F>Testo+descrittivo+offerta+%3A+asdasd<br%2F>Indirizzo+%3A+asd<br%2F>Telefono+%3A+asdsd<br%2F>Email+%3A+asd<br%2F>Sito+web+%3A+asd<br%2F>Colore+primario%3A+%23e6a1a1<br%2F>Colore+secondario%3A+%23b36868<br%2F>1-+Prodotto+asd+-+Prezzo+23423<Br%2F><br%2F><br%2F><b>Riepilogo+ordine+adesivo<%2Fb>+<br%2F><br%2F>Layout+selezionato%3A+<b>3<%2Fb><br%2F>Colore+primario+%3A+%238c4747<br%2F>Colore+secondario%3A+%23943939<br%2F>Address+%3A+asd<br%2F>Phone+%3A+asd<br%2F>Email+%3A+asd%40asd.com<br%2F>Website+%3A+asdasd<br%2F>Indirizzo+Spedizione++%3A+asdasd<br%2F>Indirizzo+%3A+asd<br%2F>Telefono+%3A+asd<br%2F>Email+%3A+asd%40asd.com<br%2F>Sito+web+%3A+asdasd<br%2F>
```

I am redirecting to this page, the message was printed before but it isn't getting printed now.

My url is like  :

```
site.com?message=thisismymessage
```

it works correctly but when the message is equal to

```
 message=<b>Volatino+riepilogo+ordine%3A<%2Fb>+<br%2F>+<br%2F>Layout+selezionato%3A+<b>2<%2Fb><br%2F>Slogan+%3A+asd<br%2F>Testo+descrittivo+offerta+%3A+asdasd<br%2F>Indirizzo+%3A+asd<br%2F>Telefono+%3A+asdsd<br%2F>Email+%3A+asd<br%2F>Sito+web+%3A+asd<br%2F>Colore+primario%3A+%23e6a1a1<br%2F>Colore+secondario%3A+%23b36868<br%2F>1-+Prodotto+asd+-+Prezzo+23423<Br%2F><br%2F><br%2F><b>Riepilogo+ordine+adesivo<%2Fb>+<br%2F><br%2F>Layout+selezionato%3A+<b>3<%2Fb><br%2F>Colore+primario+%3A+%238c4747<br%2F>Colore+secondario%3A+%23943939<br%2F>Address+%3A+asd<br%2F>Phone+%3A+asd<br%2F>Email+%3A+asd%40asd.com<br%2F>Website+%3A+asdasd<br%2F>Indirizzo+Spedizione++%3A+asdasd<br%2F>Indirizzo+%3A+asd<br%2F>Telefono+%3A+asd<br%2F>Email+%3A+asd%40asd.com<br%2F>Sito+web+%3A+asdasd<br%2F>
```

`$_GET` has no value, even output of `print_r($_GET)` is an empty array.

Comment: could you try escaping < and > with  &lt; and &gt; ?

Comment: you have to call encodeURIComponent on the parameters of the URI. For example 'message=' + encodeURI(myvar);

Comment: Yes, the URL is encoded..I encoded the value before sending it in redirect @PierreEmmanuelLallemant

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo; message=<b> i'm not sure you encoded <b>

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i am encoding the value why should I be modifying the url?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo: encodeURIComponent('<b>'); returns "%3Cb%3E" . You didnt encode it

Comment: @Danyal Saneelo because <tags> are NOT part of a valid url, AFAIK. also: to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: That's what confusing me,, Even i removed that <b> and did hit the url..No value

Comment: Could it be a length problem (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request) answer). I think a `POST` is better in this case... Also, what is the difference between the two messages in the question? Seems the same to me (using http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo: you have < and > characters in the uri, you didnt encode correctly

Comment: sending it as header('Location:my_WEBSITE.COM/my_print.php?message='.urlencode($message)); @PierreEmmanuelLallemant

Comment: i used rawurlencode as well @PierreEmmanuelLallemant

Comment: @urban checked length as well. I have been into development since long, this is sth really strange..

Answer (score 0):

encode url before you click it ,
or try this:

```js
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$arr = explode('=', $uri);
$message = '';
foreach( $arr as $k => $v ){
    if( stripos($v, 'message') !== false ){
        $message = $arr[$k+1];
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($message);exit;
```